# how can I make this type of layout dynamically using Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Can anyone just tell me the structure of XML file? and I don't want to use Table and how can I repeat that layout using for loop.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use linear-layout which orientation is horizontal.
Other way, you can use Relative layout.
For separation use Horizontal and Vertical Divider.

Comment: I don't know the concept of  Horizontal and Vertical Divider but now I got it

Comment: But still how can I put values of array-string into TextViews???

Comment: @MITPATEL `holder.txtView.setText(array[range]);`